# Should I support Co-/Contravariance for Pub-/Sub-Scenarios in C#3.0?

Tags: c#-3.0, covariance, contravariance, publish-subscribe

In my application I am creating a simple event hub that offers something for registering subscribers:

```
Subscribes<EventType>(ISubscriber<EventType> subscriber) 
// and some other methods for adding subscribers
```

And for publishing events.

```
Publish<EventType>(EventType @event)
```

Quite simple. I want to route `Publish<int>(0)` to all subscribers implementing `ISubscriber<int>`.

What's not too hard is, that I want the subscribers EventType to be contravariant. So `ISubscriber<object>` should basically consume everything. Not shure wether I want them to consume valuetypes, too.

With C#4 that is no problem, but now I'm doing this stuff with C#3 and just faking contravariance with an interface:

```
public interface IContravariantGenerics { 
  object AsVariantFor(Type[] genericParamters);
}
```

Well, now, I want to empack data into "event types" like this. The generic parameters of that events must be covariant.

```
SubX : ISubscriber<DataChanged<A>>

DataChanged<T>
  T Data {get;}
```

When I publish `Publish<DataChanged<B>>(new DataChanged<B>(new B())` (given B : A), the Subscriber should be notified with `DataChanged<A>` where Data is the B-instance passed to `DataChanged<B>`. So I need covariance support as well.

I thought of  writing a lib that supports both Co-/And Contravariance like this:

```
IMyObject<T1, T2> : IWithVariance<In, Out>
```

Which would allow conversions (not casts!) like this:

```
Obj<Fruit, Fruit> x;
IMyObject<Apple, object> x2 = x.ToVariant<Apple, object>();
```

What do you think? Is it possible? Thought of doing it using dynamic proxies.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, this will make things very complex very quickly, and it'll mean you end up writing a lot of reflection code. Can you wait for C# 4.0? ;-p

Alternatively, your code could just ignore things it doesn't know how to handle...

Comment: Right, I would have to assume stuff here and there. In cases of Ambiguity I would have to throw exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In this part:

> When I publish
>   `Publish<DataChanged<B>>(new
>   DataChanged<B>(new B())`, the
>   `Subscriber` should be notified with
>   `DataChanged<A>` where `.Data` is the
>   `B`-instance.

I may not have understood you - I can't see what `.Data` refers to, for example, and I can only guess at the relationship between B and A. Do you mean that B is derived from A?

If so, C# 4 will not necessarily make such a thing happen automatically. The types `X<A>` and `X<B>` are not compatible at all by default. If `X` is an `interface` and the type parameter is marked as `out`, then `X<B>` can be assigned to a variable of type `X<A>`. But note that this is for interfaces only, not concrete types (there is a similar provision for delegates, but that's all).

**Edit:**

So therefore what you want to do is simulate the way that `X<B>` can be assigned to a variable of type `X<A>` in C#/CLR 4.0, where X is an interface.

Suppose X is:

```
interface X<T>
{
    T Foo(int arg);

    // Note: T may only appear as an output, so this is illegal:
    // void Foo(T arg);
}
```

You have an `X<B>`, you need an `X<A>`. You know that `B` is assignable to `A`. So you need the following adaptor:

```
class WrapX_A_B : X<A>
{
    public X<B> Impl { get; set; }

    public A Foo(int arg)
    {
        return Impl.Foo(arg);
    }
}
```

You just forward each method on to the real implementation.

However, you would need such a wrapper class for every possible combination of generic outer classes and pairs of generic parameters related by inheritance. It would be a tedious, error-prone and never-complete task to write them all by hand and maintain a big lookup to pick the right one for a given situation.

So now you're into code generation to manufacture the wrapper classes at runtime.

Comment: You're right. Corrected the question.

In C#4 I would end up with ISubscriber<in T> and IChangedEvent<out T>.